# Transfer possible object states. WCF - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, data-transfer-objects

I have separeted sites of MVC and WCF services. And I have a question, how to exchange data between interface and service layer?  I would like to increase productivity, while maintaining the correct architecture. There are many constant dictionaries in my Solution, that characterize different objects. So some-times I need 5 or more service call for one page to get available values for comboBox. How to get it faster  and make it optimal for other situations?

For ex. you have a class for page.

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And you need add state for person and make selection from a value-list for edit it in interface.

**Option 1.**

```
public class Person
{
  //......
  public KeyValuePair<int,string> State {get; set;}
}
```

For fill combobox values, as you need, you should call **GetPersonStates()** from service. And its not clear what to do with value of pair when you update object.

**Option 2.**

```
public class Person
{
  //......
  public int StateId {get; set;}
}
```

For only read operation you should get stateName from service.
For fill combobox values, as you need, you should call **GetPersonStates()** from service.

**Option 3.**

```
public class Person{
   //.........
   public int StateId {get; set;}
}
public class PersonPage{
   public Person Person {get; set;}
   public Dictionary<int, string> StateDict {get; set;}
}
```

On get method you use PersonPage object (stateDict has values for comboBox). On post method you use person object whith stateId as param.

```
SavePerson(Person person, int stateId);
```

**Option 4.**

```
public class Person{
   //.........
   public int StateId {get; set;}
}
```

And store the cached values in MVC.

```
 public Dictionary<int, string> StateDict {get; set;}
```

This is very similar to the second method, but it allows to gain time.

What of option do you prefer? Or suggest others.

Comment: number 4 :-) You could even decorate with custom data attribute and a display and edittemplate, to display the string value from your cache, or edit with the complete dropdown, and the selected value.

Comment: and if you use your int as an enum, it's even easier to use display and editor template.